# Firebase Analytics APP_OPEN on Android

Tags: android, firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I made an Android app and I have integrated some tools of Firebase, but  when I include the Firebase Analytics in the event APP_OPEN Android Studio shows that "I need out bundle", but in the docs of Firebase the method I should not send bundle. How resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Bundle parameter is nullable. You can pass null if you don't intend to pass any parameters along with the APP_OPEN event.  Note that even if no parameters are suggested for APP_OPEN, you are free to log up to 25 parameters in case you have some context that you would like to capture with the event (for example, you could pass a parameter that indicates how much time has elapsed since the previous APP_OPEN event).